# Can't return a value from a property file - Java

Tags: java, properties, double

im currently trying to implement a config in my program.
I've already managed to create and also read the file but I still have trouble returning a value with a "double - method".

Creating the file:

```
public void setDefaultConfig()
{       
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");

        prop.setProperty("window_close_speed", "5000");

        prop.store(output, null);

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (output != null) {
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Reading and trying to return the speed:

```
public double retSpeed()
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");

        prop.load(input);

        double windowSpeed = Double.parseDouble(prop.getProperty("window_close_speed"));            

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {                   
                input.close();              
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }               
        }           
    }       
}
```

For some reason I can't "return windowSpeed;". Eclipse either complains about "windowSpeed cannot be resolved to a variable" or "this method must return a result of type double". windowSpeed's value is 5000.00 and seems to be completely fine when returning it with System.out.println();

Any ideas ?

Thanks for reading

Comment: `retSpeed()` is actually missing a `return` statement. Could you please post code that compiles?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Like I said, for some reason it doesnt work wherever I put it. I simply left it out for you

Comment: Please don't leave out any relevant code, especially if it's part of your problem. In any case, I've posted an answer that hopefully clarifies what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to return a value from a method, you need a `return` statement -- in all of the blocks of code that are potentially executed; the "normal" execution flow and also the flow where you `catch` exceptions:

```
public double retSpeed() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(input);
        return Double.parseDouble(prop
                .getProperty("window_close_speed"));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        // You need to return something here,
        // although it would probably be better to just
        // throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        // in case the property file cannot be read.
        return -1.0d;
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot. It finally works. Sorry for beeing a little dumb ^^ Still learning

Comment: NP, we've all been there. :)

Answer (score 1):

After catching the exception, execution continues to the end of the function and you must still return a value; for example:

```
double foo() {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble("abcd");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    // If an exception was thrown, execution reaches here
    // and we must still return a value. If you don't want 
    // this to happen because there is no sensible value you
    // could possibly return, don't catch the exception here
    return 0;
}
```

In your case, since you are only catching `IOException`, which will not be thrown by `Double.parseDouble`, you could just move the `parseDouble` and `return` down below the `try ... catch` and all will be gravy. Note, though, that this will still throw the unchecked exception `NumberFormatException` in the case of bad input (although it will keep the compiler happy).

Furthermore, you have noted that if the return is included, then `return windowSpeed;` results in a compile error about not resolving to a variable.

You have not shown your return statement, but I can only infer that your return statement is at the bottom of the function. That being the case, `windowSpeed` does not exist in the same scope, since it is only declared **inside** the `try...catch`, hence the compile error. You can either move the declaration outside the `try...catch` (i.e., elevate its scope), or move the return statement inside the `try...catch` and add an additional `return` as per my example.

Comment: Thanks on that one. Something actually seems to be wrong with the windowSpeed variable. It doesnt return an error when returning 0. When trying to return windowSpeed it once again says that I cant resolve windowSpeed to a variable.